# Regular Expression for the end of a sentence

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern in Java / Android with regular expressions. The pattern is "consonant" - "vowel" - "s" at the end of a String, like in "similares" and "científicas", but not like in "process".

My code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^aeiou][aeiou]s\\b");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(word);

Log.e(TAG, word + " contains pattern? " + matcher.matches()  );
```

This tester says I'm correct:

https://regex101.com/

This one, which is Java specific, tells me I'm correct as well:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

But in my Android app, I am unable to make them match.

My output:

```
activ contains pattern? false
program contains pattern? false
informá contains pattern? false
consult contains pattern? false
process contains pattern? false
dados contains pattern? false
domicili contains pattern? false
inform contains pattern? false
relacion contains pattern? false
outr contains pattern? false
consultoria contains pattern? false
científicas contains pattern? false
técn contains pattern? false
similares contains pattern? false
```

I also tested for

```
"[^aeiou][aeiou]s$"
```

and

```
"[^aeiou][aeiou][s]\\b"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `Matcher#find`. `matches` matches against the whole string.

Comment: Are you implementing [stemming](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) with regex? Don't know about your language, but usually there are quite a lot of exceptions.

Comment: Of course! For .matches() I would need to do something like ".*[^aeiou][aeiou]s\\b", because it tries to find an exact full match. How silly of me. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction ;)

Comment: @rustyx I am :D very observant. But I'm actually just making some very light modifications after applying a stemming algorithm. So It should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matches` tries to match the whole `String`. If your strings are split up into words and cleaned, you could add `.*` to match any character any number of times

`.` - Match any character

`*` - Quantifier: 0 or more times

`^` - Start of String

`$` - End of String

```
^\\b.*[^aeiou][aeiou]s\\b$
```

However, a caveat to note would be that if your strings aren't cleaned, it also matches non-word characters too.

"all of this whole entire sentence matches", "_./!#pes", "\n\rwas" would all also match.

---

You could also replace the `.*` with:

`\\w*` - Any number of word characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

`\\b\\w*` - Word boundary followed by any number of word characters

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you would use to match the "consonants" - "vowels" - "s":

```
^[^AEIOUaeiou]*[AEIOUaeiou]+[s]$
```

Or, for "everything" - "vowels" - "s":

```
^[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]+[s]$
```

`*`: 0 or multiple occurences

`+`: 1 or multiple occurences

Comment: Thanks. The answer is to simply add .* before the expression or using .find(). Works either way. But thank you anyway.